# How to fetch data from firebase database and keep it for 30 second and then fetch another record ,same till the last record?

Tags: java, android

Here,I have all the the id of record store in database in arraylist.**My main point is How to Keep that Record For Some Seconds and then proceed further** .

```
public class AuctionStart extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> arr;
    TextView tv;
    int i;
    DatabaseReference drf;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auction_start);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aucnm);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (null != b) {
            arr = b.getStringArrayList("list");
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorryy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

after this suppose display arraylist first element in textview for 3 seconds then simultaneously all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple and straight forward. You can use `postDelayed()`. Here is the code snippet may help you, to achieve setTimeout() like thing,

```java
new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
    new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // This will executed after 3 seconds
            // Your Logic here
        }
    }, 
3000);
```

and here is the code snippet can help you to run on interval like setInterval

```java
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
       //This will execute after every 5 second untill timer cancel()
    }
},0,5000);
```

For your case, you can do it as given,

```java
if (null != b) {
    arr = b.getStringArrayList("list");
    int index = 0;
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
           tv.setText(arr.get(index));
           if(index == (arr.size() - 1)){
               t.cancel();
           }else{
               index++;
           }

        }
    },0,3000);
}
else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Sorryy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I dont Know how Handler works exactly.How and where increment will happen. eg : when id is 1 display its all data and after 3seconds id should be change to 2 .

Comment: can you post the complete code here? it will be helpful to understand what did you said. Thanks

Comment: @ Kiran Maniya I have edit the above code.You can see there now.

Comment: check it once. I typed in here so there can be a typo. But still you'll get the idea

Comment: Not Working.App gets stopped.

Comment: Can you post a stack trace, please

Comment: check for `TimerTask` in your code. have you defined `Timer t = new Timer();` ? because your `t` is null, means you didn't define that and try once again with updated code. The method I gave you is working fine. see the docs here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-timer-class-java/

Comment: Thanks! It's working fine.can we display seconds remaining

Answer (score 0):

Use rx java and rxfirebase and there is function in rx java will repeat the process again but I don’t recommend that you can eather use cloud function and add background service on firebase cloud to togle a key to update your data since it’s real time it will auto refresh and btw you need to make sure about both of the movements will cost you money